# Convert PHP Doctrine entities managers to libraries

Tags: php, symfony, shared-libraries, cross-platform

Currently I am working with Symfony in PHP and I am thinking to convert my PHP entities managers to libraries, so to make them available across different platforms, such as iOS, Android and WP.

How should I start on this?

Comment: Do you mean the Symfony entities? This question might get flagged as too broad. I'd consider playing around with some options and come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Just read a couple of articles on how to create your own vendors from existing bundles. That seems like a logical place to start... PS: [please read the help section, this question is off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). PPS: the entity managers you're talking about probably are **Doctrine** entity managers

Comment: @thitami: Ok, so you want to use your doctrine entity managers in several projects. For that, you'll need to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), read up on how it works, and start working on your vendor bundles (dependencies). Again: this question will be closed/deleted shortly as it still is very much off-topic

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The actual requirement is to make it available cross-platform.

Comment: @thitami: Either have a shared dependency across all of your projects (which makes the entity managers available everywhere), or create a webservice or REST API. It's as simple as that...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You really understand the question? This sounds cryptic to me. What are you trying to achieve @thitami? Do you want to fetch entities from different applications written in different languages? Do you want to share code (You wrote your own entity managers??)? Do you want to share instances of entity managers?

Comment: @Gildas: I take this to mean that the functionality in the entity managers should be available on a number of projects. The ways to do this are: a) If all of the other projects are written in PHP, OP can simple create a vendor. b) If they're written in different languages, or don't have the same access rights (ie: a mobile app), the app should be made to call a service that uses said entity managers. I don't think the OP wrote his own from scratch, but rather wrote specific managers for specific entities

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. I think @EliasVanOotegem is quite close to what I am looking for. Just a short question here: What OP stands for ?

Comment: @thitami: ***O***riginal ***P***oster, the one asking the question that is